# C# IsGenericType not working as I expected

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

In the following code we have two classes, the `Parent` class uses generics:

```
abstract class Parent<T> 
{
    public T Put(T id, char value) 
    {
        return id;
    }
}

class Child : Parent<int> 
{
    public string Get(Guid guid) 
    {
        return "aei";
    }
}
```

But using reflection `IsGenericType` on the `id` parameter we get **False**...
 I think that should be True, right?

Here is my test code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var methodInfo in typeof(Child).GetMethods())
    {
        if (!methodInfo.IsVirtual && methodInfo.GetParameters().Length > 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(methodInfo.Name);
            foreach (var param in methodInfo.GetParameters())
            {
                Console.Write("  " + param.Name + " IsGenericType=");
                Console.WriteLine(param.ParameterType.IsGenericType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And output:

```
Get
  guid IsGenericType=False
Put
  id IsGenericType=False
  value IsGenericType=False
```

Comment: My troubleshooting started with an issue in Swashbuckle:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/749

Comment: The formatting in that link is so awful

Comment: @vc74 was about to type that, correct.

Comment: Just in case someone comes across this same issue, here is the working code: http://rextester.com/TREI44770

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well the result is correct. `Child` is not generic as in

```
class Child<T> : Parent<T>
```

but derived from `Parent<int>`. So the signature of `Child.Put` is

```
int Put(int id, char value);
```

and so `id` is not of a generic type, but of type `int`.

---

Edit:

A way to get that information could be something like this:

```
Type childType = typeof(Child);
MethodInfo childPut = childType.GetMethod("Put");

// get the type that initially declared the method
Type declaringType = childPut.DeclaringType;

if (declaringType.IsGenericType)
{
    // get the generic type definition (not the constructed Parent<int>)
    Type genericType = declaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    MethodInfo genericMethod = genericType.GetMethod("Put");
    ParameterInfo genericParam = genericMethod.GetParameters().First();

    // use IsGenericParameter - we want to know that the type is determined
    // by a generic argument, not if that type argument itself is generic
    Console.WriteLine(genericParam.ParameterType.IsGenericParameter);
}
```

This outputs `true` for your (special) case. I don't know your requirements, for which types the method should work. As I said in the comments, to make this an algorithm that can determine this for each parameter for all cirumstances seems complicated to me.

Comment: ...if I understand this correctly, there is no way to detect if a parameter is generic on my case

Comment: @HelderSepu your code _does_ test that. the point is the type of this parameter `id` of the method `Child.Put` **is not generic**.

Comment: @HelderSepu if you want to find out if this method is derived from a class that is a constructed generic type...that's a very broad question and I guess the algorithm for all possible class designs will be very complicated.

Comment: It's all about the parameter ```id``` there must be a way to identify (using reflection) that it was a ```T```

Comment: As mentioned in my comment below, you should use param.ParameterType.IsGenericParameter

Comment: @Amit sorry that still does not work, here is my test: http://rextester.com/YHOR75684

Comment: It does. Use it for var methodInfo in typeof(Parent<>).GetMethods(), and not var methodInfo in typeof(Child).GetMethods()

Comment: @HelderSepu added some code for your _special_ case, not saying this will work for all your types (I don't know your requirements).

Answer (score 1):

You are looping in method and parameters of child class, not parent class.

```
   var methodInfo in typeof(Child).GetMethods()
```

Child class has already initialized an object which has the method as int type parameter, not the generic type. That's how generics work.

Even if you loop it with parent class, you will need to write it as

```
var methodInfo in typeof(Parent<int>).GetMethods()
```

and

`var methodInfo in typeof(Parent<T>).GetMethods()` will not work because T is no type in itself.

As pointed in comments below,

```
var methodInfo in typeof(Parent<>).GetMethods()
```

does work.

Comment: The last sentence is not quite correct, `typeof(Parent<>).GetMethods()` works.

Comment: Yes, because when you left it blank between braces, it is taking param.ParameterType as T. It does not take a specificied T between braces. It is still giving param.ParameterType.IsGenericType as false. Why? because it is a method usage error. He should have used param.ParameterType.IsGenericParameter which gives true for your syntax. I am also correcting my answer for the last line.

Answer (score 1):

`T`is not a generic type, it's a [generic type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) which is not the same thing.

A generic type is `SomeType<T>` but `T` can be `string` or `int` or whatever, which are not generic types.